# Minesweeper draw number of nearby mines

Tags: java, swing, minesweeper

I need to do a Minesweeper game. I have most of the methods down, but I cannot figure out a way to draw the number of mines around a given tile. I have a method that returns the number of mines around that tile, but no such method to actually display that number inside the tile in the game.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3426940946811133635L;
private static final int GRID_X = 25;
private static final int GRID_Y = 25;
private static final int INNER_CELL_SIZE = 29;
private static final int TOTAL_COLUMNS = 9;
private static final int TOTAL_ROWS = 10;   //Last row has only one cell
public int x = -1;
public int y = -1;
public int mouseDownGridX = 0;
public int mouseDownGridY = 0;
private ImageIcon icon;
private static char minefield[][];
public Color[][] colorArray = new Color[TOTAL_COLUMNS][TOTAL_ROWS];
public MyPanel() {   //This is the constructor... this code runs first to initialize
    if (INNER_CELL_SIZE + (new Random()).nextInt(1) < 1) {  //Use of "random" to prevent unwanted Eclipse warning
        throw new RuntimeException("INNER_CELL_SIZE must be positive!");
    }
    if (TOTAL_COLUMNS + (new Random()).nextInt(1) < 2) {    //Use of "random" to prevent unwanted Eclipse warning
        throw new RuntimeException("TOTAL_COLUMNS must be at least 2!");
    }
    if (TOTAL_ROWS + (new Random()).nextInt(1) < 3) {   //Use of "random" to prevent unwanted Eclipse warning
        throw new RuntimeException("TOTAL_ROWS must be at least 3!");
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < TOTAL_COLUMNS; x++) {   //Top row
        colorArray[x][0] = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < TOTAL_ROWS; y++) {   //Left column
        colorArray[0][y] = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    }
    for (int x = 1; x < TOTAL_COLUMNS; x++) {   //The rest of the grid
        for (int y = 1; y < TOTAL_ROWS; y++) {
            colorArray[x][y] = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
        }
    }
    minefield = new char [TOTAL_COLUMNS][TOTAL_ROWS];
}

Random rando = new Random();
public static int mines = 10;
public int flags = 10;
public static int flagged = 0;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);


    //Compute interior coordinates
    Insets myInsets = getInsets();
    int x1 = myInsets.left;
    int y1 = myInsets.top;
    int x2 = getWidth() - myInsets.right - 1;
    int y2 = getHeight() - myInsets.bottom - 1;
    int width = x2 - x1;
    int height = y2 - y1;

    //Paint the background
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x1, y1, width + 1, height + 1);

    //Draw the grid minus the bottom row (which has only one cell)
    //By default, the grid will be 10x10 (see above: TOTAL_COLUMNS and TOTAL_ROWS) 
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (int y = 0; y <= TOTAL_ROWS - 1; y++) {
        g.drawLine(x1 + GRID_X, y1 + GRID_Y + (y * (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1)), x1 + GRID_X + ((INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1) * TOTAL_COLUMNS), y1 + GRID_Y + (y * (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1)));
    }
    for (int x = 0; x <= TOTAL_COLUMNS; x++) {
        g.drawLine(x1 + GRID_X + (x * (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1)), y1 + GRID_Y, x1 + GRID_X + (x * (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1)), y1 + GRID_Y + ((INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1) * (TOTAL_ROWS - 1)));
    }

    //Paint cell colors
    for (int x = 0; x < TOTAL_COLUMNS; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < TOTAL_ROWS; y++) {
            if ((x == 0) || (y != TOTAL_ROWS - 1)) {
                Color c = colorArray[x][y];
                g.setColor(c);
                g.fillRect(x1 + GRID_X + (x * (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1)) + 1, y1 + GRID_Y + (y * (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1)) + 1, INNER_CELL_SIZE, INNER_CELL_SIZE);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Places the mines in the field
public void placeMines() {
    int minesPlaced = 1; 
    while (minesPlaced <= mines) {
        int x = rando.nextInt(TOTAL_COLUMNS);
        int y = rando.nextInt(TOTAL_ROWS-1);
        if (minefield[x][y] != '*') {
            minefield[x][y] = '*';
            minesPlaced++;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<9; j++) {
            bombCheck(i, j);
            if (bombCheck(i, j) == 1) {
                System.out.println(i + "," + j); // for debugging purposes
            }
        }
    }repaint();
}

//checks a tile, white if there were no mines
public void check (int x, int y) {
    colorArray[x][y] = Color.WHITE ;
    repaint();
}

// Checks whether this place in the field has a bomb (1) or not (0).
public int bombCheck(int x, int y) {
    if (!(x == -1 || y == -1)) {
        if (minefield[x][y] == '*') {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            minefield[x][y] = 'c';
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}


// Checks for mines on the 8 other tiles around the target location and returns the number of mines there are. 
public int minesAround(int x, int y) {
    int mines = 0;
    mines += bombCheck(x-1, y-1);
    mines += bombCheck(x-1, y);
    mines += bombCheck(x-1, y+1);
    mines += bombCheck(x, y-1);
    mines += bombCheck(x, y+1);
    mines += bombCheck(x+1, y-1);
    mines += bombCheck(x+1, y);
    mines += bombCheck(x+1, y+1);
    if (mines > 0) {
        return mines;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

//What I've come up with so far for drawing the number in the tile. Does not work.
public void draw (Graphics g, int n, int x, int y) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString("" + n + "", x, y);
}

//Recursive method
public void checkAround(int x, int y) {
    int minx, miny, maxx, maxy;
    check(x,y);
    minx = (x <= 0 ? 0 : x - 1);
    miny = (y <= 0 ? 0 : y - 1);
    maxx = (x >= TOTAL_COLUMNS - 1 ? TOTAL_COLUMNS - 1 : x + 1);
    maxy = (y >= TOTAL_ROWS - 2 ? TOTAL_ROWS - 2 : y + 1);
    for (int i = minx; i < maxx; i ++) {
        for (int j = miny; j <= maxy; j ++) {
                if (bombCheck(i,j) == 0 && colorArray[i][j] != Color.WHITE) {
                    check(i,j);
                    if (minesAround(i,j) == 0) {
                        checkAround(i,j);
                    }
                    if (minesAround(i,j) == 1) {
                        draw(getGraphics(),1,i,j); // Does not work.
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

//Flag
public int checkflag(int x, int y){
    int status = 0;
    if (!(x == -1 || y == -1)) {
        if (colorArray[x][y] == Color.RED) {
            status += 1;
        }else {
            status += 0;
        }
    }
    return status;
}

//Resets field
public void reset() {
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_COLUMNS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ;j < TOTAL_ROWS; j++) {
            colorArray[i][j] = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
            minefield[i][j] = ' ';
            MyMouseAdapter.f = 1;
            repaint();
        }
    }
    placeMines();
}


public int getGridX(int x, int y) {
    Insets myInsets = getInsets();
    int x1 = myInsets.left;
    int y1 = myInsets.top;
    x = x - x1 - GRID_X;
    y = y - y1 - GRID_Y;
    if (x < 0) {   //To the left of the grid
        return -1;
    }
    if (y < 0) {   //Above the grid
        return -1;
    }
    if ((x % (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1) == 0) || (y % (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1) == 0)) {   //Coordinate is at an edge; not inside a cell
        return -1;
    }
    x = x / (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1);
    y = y / (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1);
    if (x == 0 && y == TOTAL_ROWS - 1) {    //The lower left extra cell
        return x;
    }
    if (x < 0 || x > TOTAL_COLUMNS - 1 || y < 0 || y > TOTAL_ROWS - 2) {   //Outside the rest of the grid
        return -1;
    }
    return x;
}
public int getGridY(int x, int y) {
    Insets myInsets = getInsets();
    int x1 = myInsets.left;
    int y1 = myInsets.top;
    x = x - x1 - GRID_X;
    y = y - y1 - GRID_Y;
    if (x < 0) {   //To the left of the grid
        return -1;
    }
    if (y < 0) {   //Above the grid
        return -1;
    }
    if ((x % (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1) == 0) || (y % (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1) == 0)) {   //Coordinate is at an edge; not inside a cell
        return -1;
    }
    x = x / (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1);
    y = y / (INNER_CELL_SIZE + 1);
    if (x == 0 && y == TOTAL_ROWS - 1) {    //The lower left extra cell
        return y;
    }
    if (x < 0 || x > TOTAL_COLUMNS - 1 || y < 0 || y > TOTAL_ROWS - 2) {   //Outside the rest of the grid
        return -1;
    }
    return y;
}

public ImageIcon getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(ImageIcon icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}
}
```

-

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
    public static int f = 1;
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        switch (e.getButton()) {
        case 1:     //Left mouse button
            Component c = e.getComponent();
            while (!(c instanceof JFrame)) {
                c = c.getParent();
                if (c == null) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            JFrame myFrame = (JFrame) c;
            MyPanel myPanel = (MyPanel) myFrame.getContentPane().getComponent(0);
            Insets myInsets = myFrame.getInsets();
            int x1 = myInsets.left;
            int y1 = myInsets.top;
            e.translatePoint(-x1, -y1);
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();
            myPanel.x = x;
            myPanel.y = y;
            myPanel.mouseDownGridX = myPanel.getGridX(x, y);
            myPanel.mouseDownGridY = myPanel.getGridY(x, y);
            myPanel.repaint();
            break;
        case 3:     //Right mouse button
            Component c1 = e.getComponent();
            while (!(c1 instanceof JFrame)) {
                c = c1.getParent();
                if (c == null) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            JFrame myFrame1 = (JFrame)c1;
            MyPanel myPanel1 = (MyPanel) myFrame1.getContentPane().getComponent(0);  //Can also loop among components to find MyPanel
            Insets myInsets1 = myFrame1.getInsets();
            int x2 = myInsets1.left;
            int y2 = myInsets1.top;
            e.translatePoint(-x2, -y2);
            int x3 = e.getX();
            int y3 = e.getY();
            myPanel1.x = x3;
            myPanel1.y = y3;
            myPanel1.mouseDownGridX = myPanel1.getGridX(x3, y3);
            myPanel1.mouseDownGridY = myPanel1.getGridY(x3, y3);
            break;
        default:    //Some other button (2 = Middle mouse button, etc.)
            //Do nothing
            break;
        }
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        switch (e.getButton()) {
        case 1:     //Left mouse button
            Component c = e.getComponent();
            while (!(c instanceof JFrame)) {
                c = c.getParent();
                if (c == null) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            JFrame myFrame = (JFrame)c;
            MyPanel myPanel = (MyPanel) myFrame.getContentPane().getComponent(0);  //Can also loop among components to find MyPanel
            Insets myInsets = myFrame.getInsets();
            int x1 = myInsets.left;
            int y1 = myInsets.top;
            e.translatePoint(-x1, -y1);
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();
            myPanel.x = x;
            myPanel.y = y;
            int gridX = myPanel.getGridX(x, y);
            int gridY = myPanel.getGridY(x, y);
            if ((myPanel.mouseDownGridX == -1) || (myPanel.mouseDownGridY == -1)) {
                //Had pressed outside
                //Do nothing
            } else {
                if ((gridX == -1) || (gridY == -1)) {
                    //Do nothing
                }else if (gridX == 0 && gridY == 9) {
                        myPanel.reset();
                } else {
                    if ((myPanel.mouseDownGridX != gridX) || (myPanel.mouseDownGridY != gridY)) {
                        //Released the mouse button on a different cell where it was pressed
                        //Do nothing
                    } else {
                        //Released the mouse button on the same cell where it was pressed
                        if (!(myPanel.mouseDownGridX == -1) || (myPanel.mouseDownGridY == -1)) {
                            if (!(myPanel.colorArray[gridX][gridY] == Color.RED)) {
                                if (myPanel.bombCheck(gridX, gridY) == 0) {
                                    myPanel.checkAround(gridX, gridY);
                                }
                                else{
                                    myPanel.colorArray[gridX][gridY] = Color.BLACK ;
                                    System.out.println("You've Lost!");
                                    myPanel.reset();
                                    myPanel.repaint();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            myPanel.repaint();
            break;
        case 3:     //Right mouse button
            Component c1 = e.getComponent();
            while (!(c1 instanceof JFrame)) {
                c = c1.getParent();
                if (c == null) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            JFrame myFrame1 = (JFrame)c1;
            MyPanel myPanel1 = (MyPanel) myFrame1.getContentPane().getComponent(0);  //Can also loop among components to find MyPanel
            Insets myInsets1 = myFrame1.getInsets();
            int x2 = myInsets1.left;
            int y2 = myInsets1.top;
            e.translatePoint(-x2, -y2);
            int x3 = e.getX();
            int y3 = e.getY();
            myPanel1.x = x3;
            myPanel1.y = y3;
            int gridX1 = myPanel1.getGridX(x3, y3);
            int gridY1 = myPanel1.getGridY(x3, y3);
            int flags = 10;
            if ((myPanel1.mouseDownGridX == -1) || (myPanel1.mouseDownGridY == -1)) {
                //Had pressed outside
                //Do nothing
            } else {
                if ((gridX1 == -1) || (gridY1 == -1)) {
                    //Is releasing outside
                    //Do nothing
                } else {
                    if ((myPanel1.mouseDownGridX != gridX1) || (myPanel1.mouseDownGridY != gridY1)) {
                    }else{
                        if (!(myPanel1.colorArray[gridX1][gridY1] == Color.WHITE)) {
                            if (myPanel1.checkflag(gridX1, gridY1) == 0) {
                                if (!(f > flags)) {
                                    if (myPanel1.bombCheck(gridX1, gridY1) == 1) {
                                        MyPanel.flagged ++;
                                        if (MyPanel.flagged == 10) {
                                            System.out.println("You've Won! Congratulations!");
                                            myPanel1.reset();
                                            myPanel1.colorArray[gridX1][gridY1] = Color.LIGHT_GRAY ;
                                            myPanel1.repaint();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    myPanel1.colorArray[gridX1][gridY1] = Color.RED ;
                                    myPanel1.repaint();
                                    f ++;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                myPanel1.colorArray[gridX1][gridY1] = Color.LIGHT_GRAY ;
                                myPanel1.repaint();
                                f --;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:    //Some other button (2 = Middle mouse button, etc.)
            //Do nothing
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Color Grid");
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setLocation(400, 150);
        myFrame.setSize(400, 400);

        MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
        myFrame.add(myPanel);

        MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
        myFrame.addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);


        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myPanel.placeMines();
    }
}
```

This is only my first year studying Computer science, but if my intuition is correct, my draw method is drawing the number behind the tiles. These are just my thoughts, I have relatively little to no experience with Java.

Comment: Post something runnable would be helpful.

Comment: Don't rely on `static` to provide a cross object communications, this is why we have listeners and models

Comment: The static keywords were not done by me, I had to use them as source code, but I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `paintComponent()` add something like this:

```
Font f = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12); // choose a font for the numbers
g.setFont(f);

// Draw cell numbers
for (int x = 0; x < TOTAL_COLUMNS; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < TOTAL_ROWS; y++) {
        if (/* check if the (x,y) cell is uncovered */) {
            int around = minesAround(x, y);
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(around), /*cell x coord*/, /*cell y coord*/);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use an [image](http://www.crisgdwrites.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/minesweeper_tiles.jpg) for each cell number instead of using a string.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually thought about this after going to bed and was anxious to try it out. On a note, g.drawText did not work for me, maybe you meant g.drawString? That's what worked for me. Anyways thanks again!

Comment: you're right, sorry I didn't test my code :) glad to have been helpful, you're welcome! have fun coding